# Openfire: Found user that never left a previous conversation

Tags: php, chat, openfire, groupchat, web-chat

We're facing few weird issues while using open-fire for one to one and group chat.

Following are the configuration and third-party libraries we're using to achieve web chat functionality.

- Version of Openfire is 4.1.4
- Version of PHP 5.5 MySql - 5.7.18
- strophe.js [Attached to this link](http://www.transfernow.net/41hd7639cfl1)

Attached, please find the screen shots to know the exact warnings what we are getting at the time of chat.

- Following picture shows multiple sessions created for a single user by open-fire.
  [image]
- Plugins list used by openfire for chat
  [image]
- Shows errors / warnings generated by openfire 
  [image]

We're not sure why this issue is occurring that's why we open this issue over here to know your thoughts.

Our server provider suggests that the session of user is created multiple time by openfire. That's why session is not closed properly at the time of logout or user left any conversation because of that memory gets leak and openfire crashes frequently and chat doesn't work.

Any quick help would be really appreciated.